# checking if start_date column and end_date column covers any date values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns (START_DATE and END_DATE) where they are used to check against a column of date values (DATE_VALUE column), and if any date in DATE_VALUE column is between START_DATE and END_DATE, to flag out a HIT in new column beside START_DATE/END_DATE. For example below: in row 1 - 30/01/2022 is between 01/01/2022 and 31/02/2022, so it's a HIT. In row 4, there are no date values in DATE_VALUE column falling within 19/02/2022 and 24/02/2022.

Below is the screenshot. I figure it requires using of array formula, but i am quite stuck. seeking your help.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to compare F2 with only B2:C range or against every date range (B2:C2, B3:C3 and so on) ?

Comment: i want to compare all values of F2 against B2:C2 date range which will derive a HIT or no HIT result in D2.

Comment: @theluncheonmeat i have posted in answers please check. You need to use `SUMPRODUCT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SUMPRODUCT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$5>=B2)*($F$2:$F$5<=C2)),"HIT","NO HIT")
```

---

And Fill Down!

---

If you are using `MS365` using `MAP()` for a spill range.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(r,F2:F5,
MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(SUM((r>=x)*(r<=y)),"HIT","NO HIT"))))
```

---

**EDIT:**

To get the number of occurrences, just remove the `IF()` part.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(r,F2:F5,
MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((r>=x)*(r<=y)))))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2` --> If you dont need a spilled array like above then try the one in below which you need to fill down!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$5>=B2)*($F$2:$F$5<=C2))
```

---

Comment: HI! thank you. can i know, if instead of 'HIT' or 'no HIT', I want to know to return the number of occurrence the date_Value dates fall within the range (e.g. B2:C2), how should your fornula in sumproduct be changed? thank you !

Comment: @theluncheonmeat if you remove the `IF()` you will certainly get the counts. Need to enter only this `=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$5>=B2)*($F$2:$F$5<=C2))`

Comment: @theluncheonmeat i have updated in answers

Answer (score 2):

Just use COUNTIFS to count how many DATE_VALUES are contained in the range delimited by START and END. If the count is higher than 0 means HIT, else NO HIT:

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$5,">="&B2,$F$2:$F$5,"<="&C2)>0,"HIT","NO HIT")
```

No need of array formula

**UPDATE:** If you just want to count how many DATE_VALUES are inside the range, just use COUNTIFS:

```
COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$5,">="&B2,$F$2:$F$5,"<="&C2)
```

Comment: HI! thank you. can i know, if instead of 'HIT' or 'no HIT', I want to know to return the number of occurrence the date_Value dates fall within the range (e.g. B4:C4 will return '2'), how should your fornula in your countifs formula be changed? thank you !